# Get the highest numeric file name(as int) from directory - Java

Tags: java, dir

Given a `File dir` I need to find the highest numeric file name(if any exist)

My approach:

```
// get the highest numeric file name(as int) from given directory
public static final int getHighestNumericFileName(File dir) {
    int result = -1;

    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        String name = f.getName();
        name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('.'));
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(name)) {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(name);
            if (val > result)
                result = val;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Considering the file count in the folder can get quite large(300k+) my concern is performance related.

**Is this at all an acceptable solution? And is there a better way?**

Comment: Are all the files within the folder relevant (i.e. do you need to check all the files or only files which follow a certain name pattern)?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula All the fully numeric names are game, the rest are of no interest... I was actually hoping for some clever regex solution but cant think of anything...

Comment: Well if you need to use text files to manage 300k it gets real silly. A database would be a better idea

Comment: @YaWang I didn't say it was text files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java 7 NIO's `DirectoryStream` to go through your files using a filter to make sure you ignore the files that are not relevant to you.

Here is the filter:

```
class NumericFilter implements DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\d+\\..*");

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
        return PATTERN.matcher(entry.getFileName().toString()).matches();
    }

}
```

And here is the code using it:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dir), new NumericFilter())) {
    for (Path path : stream) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

This will only go through files with completely numeric names (without or with any extension).

---

Just for the record, here is a slightly simpler way to do the same with Java 8:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\..*");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dir),
        entry -> pattern.matcher(entry.getFileName().toString()).matches())) {
    for (Path path : stream) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this could work... I'm assuming `"[0-9]*.*"` this will take into account any non numeric postfix so changing it to `"[0-9].*"` should do the trick.

Comment: @DimaMaligin `[0-9].*` will match only files with a single number on its name. I'm working on a new glob.

Comment: How about `"[0-9]+.*"` then

Comment: Globs are different from regular expressions, this won't work. They actually can't get the job done here, although regular expressions can! I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Not with that lambda expression. Let me add a Java 7 version.

Comment: Its fine... i can do it my self... thank you for your effort!

Comment: @DimaMaligin Too late :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to sort the files and take the first entry or the last entry.

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("\\d+.txt");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
Arrays.sort(files);//sorts lexicographically
```

Comment: I can't assume all the files are numerically named, in which case ill still have to iterate to skip the non numeric ones after sort. And there is no way of knowing if there are numeric names at all in which case it'll iterate over all of them...

Comment: You could use a regex filter to get only the files with numeric in it.

Comment: Very nice... seems like it can work. Any suggestion on implementing a non-lexicographical sort? Id rather avoid self implementing sorting...

Answer (score 0):

For very large amounts of numbers, the best way to sort them is with a [`Heap Sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Comparison_with_other_sorts). For example

```
int[] yourFiles = {} //Puts all file names in array
HeapSort.sort(yourFiles);
result = yourFiles[yourFilens.length-1];
```

**HeapSort**

```
public class HeapSort 
{
    private static int[] a;
    private static int n;
    private static int left;
    private static int right;
    private static int largest;


    public static void buildheap(int []a)
    {
        n=a.length-1;
        for(int i=n/2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            maxheap(a,i);
        }
    }

    public static void maxheap(int[] a, int i)
    { 
        left=2*i;
        right=2*i+1;
        if(left <= n && a[left] > a[i])
        {
            largest=left;
        }
        else
        {
            largest=i;
        }

        if(right <= n && a[right] > a[largest])
        {
            largest=right;
        }

        if(largest!=i)
        {
            exchange(i,largest);
            maxheap(a, largest);
        }
    }

    public static void exchange(int i, int j)
    {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t; 
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a0)
    {
        a=a0;
        buildheap(a);

        for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
        {
            exchange(0, i);
            n=n-1;
            maxheap(a, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

An example implementation of this would be.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] test = {1,5,6,8,6,41};
        HeapSort.sort(test);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
}
```

Comment: @UmaKanth I'll give you it is easier but a heapsort is a lot more efficient at sorting very large data amounts

Comment: I would still have to iterate over all the files in the directory check if the name is numeric stick it in another `int[]` then sort it... I'm sorry but this will actually take longer than my approach since I can just store the highest value while iterating the names the first time.